# creation of certificate using openssl

Tags: openssl, key, certificate

Hello I am following this guide to create certificate using openssl for a project ( our professor gave it to us)
http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates#SSLCert-7

But I am using windows and commands there are given for linux. For example at some point, they state "To create, while in the 'sslcert' directory, type:

```
    openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout \
    private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365 -config ./openssl.cnf

You will be prompted for information and a password. Do not loose this
password, make sure it is a secure one, and back up the two files that
are created.

The two files that are created are cacert.pem, which is the one you can
give to others for import in their browsers, and cakey.pem, which will
be in the private directory."
```

I don't know where to type this command, I tried it in openssl and it gave me an error, can anyone help me do this on windows?

Comment: it's one command. the ``\`` just indicates "line break here for legibility". it's all one single LONG command. for windows just change the `/` directory separators to ``\``.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365 -config openssl.cnf
```

Exist private/cakey.pem ???

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know where to type this command

Do you have OpenSSL installed on the Windows machine? Its usually painful to build it from sources on Windows. I would encourage you to grab Thomas Hruska's [Win32OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) from Shining Light Productions.

Win32OpenSSL has a Windows installer, so it should be painless. Be sure to install into the system directory so the executables are available without the need to modify `PATH`s.

With Win32OpenSSL installed, you can execute the commands in a command prompt. The command prompt is the black box on Windows. You can open the command prompt with the following:

[image]

---

> But I am using windows and commands there are given for linux

The commands are the same (sans the direction of the slashes).

Comment: I installed a 64 bit openssl in my windows and I opened openssl.exe to type the command, is it wrong?